# Create an exceptional A3 page within an A4-based report

Tags: floats, minipage, paper-size

I created a picture within a tool that fits exactly in an A3 page. However I need to place this picture within an report that has A4 pages by default. The picture contains lots of information so I don't want to scale it down.

Right now I have the following code:

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{aPic}
  \captionof{figure}{Wanna be lay down horizontally in an A3 page!}
  \label{fig1}
\end{minipage}
```

So how I can do put the picture in my report?. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If the image fits exactly within an A3 page and you don't have to do anything extra to it, include it using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).

Comment: @Werner what about the header, footer, and figure number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here a solution without KOMA. Please note, you need to use `--shell-escape` to compile your document, e.g. `pdflatex --shell-escape thisdocument.tex`.

The page style can be adjusted, as well as a section entry and/or figure label. The pagestyle is set to plain. Please modify that entry accordingly to the name of your pagestyle.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{caption} % define caption and label

\begin{filecontents}{mwe_a3}
\documentclass[a3paper,landscape,fullpage]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
I'm your a3paper page :-)
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{a4 page}
first page in a4

\immediate\write18{pdflatex mwe_a3}
\clearpage
{\setlength\paperwidth{420mm} %A3
\setlength\paperheight{297mm} %A3
\setlength\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
\setlength\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\includepdf[scale=1,noautoscale, %
                pagecommand={%
                \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{a3 paper section}%
                \captionof{figure}{text}\label{labelname}%
                \thispagestyle{plain}}]{mwe_a3}}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: very interesting answer, thanks a lot. However I have two main problems: 1.The figure caption does not reflect the figure caption within the document. 2. How to add the header that is going through the document on the top of the included pdf?

Comment: I haved modified my answer accordingly. The 2nd problem can be solved by using the pagecommand key of pdfpages. For the issue with the figure caption I do not have a solution at hand right now :-). My assumption was that this would not be necessary ('exactly fits one a3 page'). You can reference it in the TOC though.

Comment: Okay, adding a figure label was easier than I initially thought. I udpated my answer again.

Comment: Great, 99% there!(Voted! :-). Do you know how I can move the page numbers to the corner of the A3 page? Somehow it printed as if it is an A4 paper.

Comment: You need to further tweak your page layout using the given `\setlength` commands, e.g., by adjusting `\textheight` and `\textwidth`. A package that will help you determining the correct page layout is `\usepackage{showframes}`

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the `geometry` package does not allow you to change the paper size mid-document. However, as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812892/change-paper-size-in-the-middle-of-a-latex-document), this is possible in the KOMA-script class:

```
\documentclass[version=last, pagesize=auto, paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\null
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=a3}
\recalctypearea

\null
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=a4}
\recalctypearea

\null

\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer the non KOMA version better.