# How to avoid a blank page after selecting a larger paper size for a very large graphic?

Tags: pdf, miktex, texworks

I am writing a paper about computer history, especially about a project computer equipped with both core memory and semiconductor dynamic RAMs 40 years ago.

I have some very large graphics of the large (45 cm) memory boards which should have original size. So I use A4paper for the text and A0paper for the graphics. There should be only some labels on the A0paper, but no sentences at all. See these [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812892/change-paper-size-in-the-middle-of-a-latex-document) [and](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101559/create-an-exceptional-a3-page-within-an-a4-based-report/101561#101561).

Changing from A4paper to A0paper and back again works well. Using the measurement tool of adobe PDF reader to check a distance is OK. But the image follows after a blank page on the second sheet of the large paper.

Comment: My guess (since your MWE is not testable) is that \KOMAoptions and \newgeometry are each forcing a page change.  You don't need both.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your guess. But when I use \newgeometry only the paper size is not changed. If I use \KOMAoptions only, the paper size is changed, the graphic crosses the page border and a new page is inserted. If I use both, the graphic is centered and a new page is inserted. My MWE should be testable if you include another pdf available on your computer.

Comment: A complete MWE starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.  That is, one should be able to copy and run the code as is.  Also, use example-image instead of files we don't have access to.

Comment: I started a new section before changing the paper size and the empty page disapeared. I still use both \KOMAoptions and \newgeometry